# C#: How can i modify selected text/wrap content etc?

Tags: c#, wpf

what i want to acheive is similar to the editor in stackoverflow. where if i press bold, it will wrap my selected text with some text (in this case **)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public Window1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    textBox.KeyDown += OnTextBoxKeyDown;
}

private void OnTextBoxKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.B
         && (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control)
    {
        string boldText = "**";
        int beginMarkerIndex = textBox.SelectionStart;
        int endMarkerIndex = beginMarkerIndex + textBox.SelectionLength + boldText.Length;
        textBox.Text = textBox.Text.Insert(beginMarkerIndex, boldText)
                                   .Insert(endMarkerIndex, boldText); 
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but i dont really understand why you need to use `e.Key & Key.B` can't i just do `e.Key == Key.Tab`? for `(Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control` ... oh i also notice the use of `&` what does that do? but to bring this further, how can i see if Ctrl+Shift+B (as an example) if pressed

Comment: @ jiewmeng: Actually, you are right that in this case, e.Key == Key.B would do. The & pattern (bitwise AND) is for Flags enumerations. Basically, the ModifierKeys enum can be in several 'states' at once, so that is how you test whether a particular 'state' is in effect or not. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229062.aspx

Comment: @jiewmeng: To test if 'Shift'  is also being pressed, add && (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Shift) == ModifierKeys.Shift) to the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested:

```
TextBox textBox;
// ...
string bolded = "**" + textBox.SelectedText + "**";
int index = textBox.SelectionStart;
textBox.Text.Remove(textBox.SelectionStart, textBox.SelectionLength);
textBox.Text.Insert(index, bolded);
```